# fade-out text, replace text, then fade-in again [reactjs]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a list of `p` tags, and I want to cycle through this list, by fading in one `p` tag, then fading out, then again fading in after replacing it.

Here is this codepen in jQuery: https://codepen.io/motion333/pen/EBBGVM

I am trying to do this in React by this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        (function() {

            var quotes = document.getElementsByClassName('tagline-text');
            var quoteIndex = -1;

            function showNextQuote() {
              ++quoteIndex;
              document.querySelectorAll(".tagline-text")[quoteIndex % quotes.length].fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, showNextQuote);
            }

            showNextQuote();

          })();
}, []);
```

And this is the conainer:

```html
<div className="tagline h-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <p className="tagline-text">Your Business</p>
    <p className="tagline-text">Your Brand</p>
    <p className="tagline-text">Your Content</p>
    <p className="tagline-text">Your Portfolio</p>
    <p className="tagline-text">You.</p>
</div>
```

But it gives me this error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...)[(quoteIndex % quotes.length)].fadeIn is not a function
```

Comment: `fadeIn` is a jQuery method, but you are not dealing with jQuery objects here, but with normal HTMLElement objects.

Comment: yes I have realised that. What will be the actual equivalents of fade in and fade out methods in JS?

Comment: There a no native equivalents. You will either have to implement them yourself, or go check what alternatives react might explicitly provide(?).

Comment: Not able to do it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should do it.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const texts = ["Your Business", "Your Brand", "Your Content", "Your Portfolio", "You."];
const time_between_text = 2; // text show for 2s before fade out.
const transition_duration = 0.5;

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      setShow(p => {
        if(p === texts.length - 1) p = -transition_duration;
        else p = p + transition_duration;
        return p;
      });
    }, time_between_text * 1000)
    
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [])

  return <div className="pContainer">
    {texts.map((t, i) => <p key={i} style={{ opacity: `${show === i ? 1 : 0}`, transitionDuration: `${time_between_text + transition_duration}s` }}>{t}</p>)}
</div>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```css
.pContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.pContainer p {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```